# undefined reference to create object name from factory class

Tags: c++, macros, factory-pattern

Macro class creates objects in main function by call `CREATE_MAPPER("HelloMapper");`. Mapper.h registers object to factory class to macro in [class_register.h](https://gist.github.com/Chatsiri/4b4176c045246965ed4d) follow as example below

class_register.h

```
#ifndef COMMON_BASE_CLASS_REGISTER_H_
#define COMMON_BASE_CLASS_REGISTER_H_

#include <map>
#include <string> 
enter code here

#define CLASS_REGISTER_DEFINE_REGISTRY(register_name, base_class_name) \
class ObjectCreatorRegistry_##register_name { \
public: \
typedef base_class_name* (*Creator)(); \
\
ObjectCreatorRegistry_##register_name() \
: m_default_creator(NULL) {} \
~ObjectCreatorRegistry_##register_name() {} \
\
void SetDefaultCreator(Creator creator) { \
m_default_creator = creator; \
} \
\
void AddCreator(std::string entry_name, Creator creator) { \
m_creator_registry[entry_name] = creator; \
} \
\
base_class_name* CreateObject(const std::string& entry_name); \
\
private: \
typedef std::map<std::string, Creator> CreatorRegistry; \
Creator m_default_creator; \
CreatorRegistry m_creator_registry; \
}; \
\
inline ObjectCreatorRegistry_##register_name& \
GetRegistry_##register_name() { \
static ObjectCreatorRegistry_##register_name registry; \
return registry; \
} \
\
class DefaultObjectCreatorRegister_##register_name { \
public: \
DefaultObjectCreatorRegister_##register_name( \
ObjectCreatorRegistry_##register_name::Creator creator) { \
GetRegistry_##register_name().SetDefaultCreator(creator); \
} \
~DefaultObjectCreatorRegister_##register_name() {} \
}; \
\
class ObjectCreatorRegister_##register_name { \
public: \
ObjectCreatorRegister_##register_name( \
const std::string& entry_name, \
ObjectCreatorRegistry_##register_name::Creator creator) { \
GetRegistry_##register_name().AddCreator(entry_name, \
creator); \
} \
~ObjectCreatorRegister_##register_name() {} \
}

#define CLASS_REGISTER_IMPLEMENT_REGISTRY(register_name, base_class_name) \
base_class_name* ObjectCreatorRegistry_##register_name::CreateObject( \
const std::string& entry_name) { \
Creator creator = m_default_creator; \
CreatorRegistry::const_iterator it = \
m_creator_registry.find(entry_name); \
if (it != m_creator_registry.end()) { \
creator = it->second; \
} \
\
if (creator != NULL) { \
return (*creator)(); \
} else { \
return NULL; \
} \
}

#define CLASS_REGISTER_DEFAULT_OBJECT_CREATOR(register_name, \
base_class_name, \
class_name) \
base_class_name* DefaultObjectCreator_##register_name##class_name() { \
return new class_name; \
} \
DefaultObjectCreatorRegister_##register_name \
g_default_object_creator_register_##register_name##class_name( \
DefaultObjectCreator_##register_name##class_name)

#define CLASS_REGISTER_OBJECT_CREATOR(register_name, \
base_class_name, \
entry_name_as_string, \
class_name) \
base_class_name* ObjectCreator_##register_name##class_name() { \
return new class_name; \
} \
ObjectCreatorRegister_##register_name \
g_object_creator_register_##register_name##class_name( \
entry_name_as_string, \
ObjectCreator_##register_name##class_name)

#define CLASS_REGISTER_CREATE_OBJECT(register_name, entry_name_as_string) \
GetRegistry_##register_name().CreateObject(entry_name_as_string)

#endif // COMMON_BASE_CLASS_REGISTER_H_
```

mapper.h (the interface definition):

```
#include "class_register.h"
 class Mapper {
 };

 CLASS_REGISTER_DEFINE_REGISTRY(mapper_register, Mapper);

 #define REGISTER_MAPPER(mapper_name) \
 CLASS_REGISTER_OBJECT_CREATOR( \
 mapper_register, Mapper, #mapper_name, mapper_name) \

 #define CREATE_MAPPER(mapper_name_as_string) \
 CLASS_REGISTER_CREATE_OBJECT(mapper_register, mapper_name_as_string)`
```

hello_mapper.cc (an implementation of Mapper):

```
 #include "mapper.h"
 class HelloMapper : public Mapper {
 };
 REGISTER_MAPPER(HelloMapper);
```

mapper_user.cc (the final user of all registered mappers):

```
 #include "mapper.h"
 CLASS_REGISTER_IMPLEMENT_REGISTRY(mapper_register, Mapper);
 int main(){
   Mapper* mapper = CREATE_MAPPER("HelloMapper");
 }
```

After compile code follow command line such as

`g++ -g -o mapper mapper_user.cc mapper.h class_register.h hello_mapper.cc`

G++ show an error after compiled source code.

`mapper_user.cc:line: undefined reference to ObjectCreatorRegistry_mapper_register::CreateObject(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'`

Why main() function cannot undefined reference to `ObjectCreatorRegistry_mapper_register` in macro?

Comment: I believe that you mean to ask a clear question, but regrettably I do not understand it.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: With crazy macros like this, run `g++ -E` and review the preprocessed output. I suspect you forgot to provide a definition of the `CreateObject` member function.

Comment: @thang I improved my question.

Comment: @T.C. It cannot use -E flag with multiple file :(

Comment: @jxh I was defined macros class at [class_register.h](https://gist.github.com/Chatsiri/4b4176c045246965ed4d)

Comment: @jxh My post embedded all class.

Answer (score 2):

### The fish:

> <sub>*Note that this answer was given before the OP edited the question adding this suggested fix.</sub>

The compilation error is due to a missing method `ObjectCreatorRegistry_mapper_register::CreateObject()`. This is only created if `CLASS_REGISTER_IMPLEMENT_REGISTRY()` is used. You need to add this line to an appropriate source file:

```
CLASS_REGISTER_IMPLEMENT_REGISTRY(mapper_register, Mapper);
```

### How to fish:

The error message looks indecipherable, but if you concentrate on the class name and the method, it should be easier to understand:

> `mapper_user.cc:line:`*`undefined reference to`*
>  **`ObjectCreatorRegistry_mapper_register::CreateObject(`**
>   `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)`

The *undefined reference* message to a method **`CreateObject`** indicates that the method has a prototype, but is not defined. Searching through the macros for `CreateObject` shows that a definition is created by using the `CLASS_REGISTER_IMPLEMENT_REGISTRY` macro.

### On an unrelated note...

Do not specify the header files on the compilation line.

```
g++ -g -o mapper mapper_user.cc hello_mapper.cc
```

Comment: Main class edited by add macro name `CLASS_REGISTER_IMPLEMENT_REGISTRY(mapper_register, Mapper);`. Mapper class can register in macro object. :D

Comment: Are you claiming it was always there and you forgot to mention it, or are you saying that you still have the ***exact same problem*** after adding it?

Comment: That's incorrect, because adding the line I pointed out will make the error message go away. The whole point of the question was how to deal with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

`base_class_name* ObjectCreatorRegistry_##register_name::CreateObject(` is declared by `CLASS_REGISTER_DEFINE_REGISTRY`. Which is compiled by mapper.h

It is supposed to be implemented by macro `CLASS_REGISTER_IMPLEMENT_REGISTRY`. But no one calls it....so the `ObjectCreatorRegistry_##register_name` class functions are not implemented!